# How do I make a content slider that shows the next slide when the user scrolls vertically or clicks one of the bottom nav tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

This is my first post on Stack Overflow so sorry if I'm not clear in what I'm saying. But basically I'm working on a little school project and it's basically an All About Me site to refresh on what we've learned over the summer. I have tabs on the bottom of the screen for navigation and I have content in the center of the screen. Upon clicking a new tab or scrolling down, I want the corresponding div to slide into where the old content was. I don't have a huge knowledge of JavaScript so I have no idea how to go about doing this. I've been looking at image sliders but those aren't really what I'm looking for. I'm looking for something like this: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/8/

**This is how it looks right now:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBD07.jpg

**This is basically all of my HTML so far:**

```
<main class="content-container">
<section class="slider animated fadeInDown">
    <div class="intro-content">
        <h1>Hi, my name is Brian Hurtado.</h1>
        <h3>I enjoy making beautiful and innovative websites.</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="summer-content">
        <h1>This is my text about summer.</h1>
        <h3>This is some more text about my summer.</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="design-content">
        <h1>This is some text about web design.</h1>
        <h3>This is some more text about web design.</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="schedule-content">
        <h1>This is some text about my schedule.</h1>
        <h3>Probably going to put a table in here.</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="site-content">
        <h1>This is some text about what I want to do with the school site.</h1>
        <h3>This is some more text about what I want to do with the school site.</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="goals-content">
        <h1>These are my goals that I hope to achieve in the future.</h1>
        <h3>I have to think of some goals.</h3>
    </div>
</section> 
</main>

<nav class="main-nav">
<ul>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="img/home.png">
            </span>
            <b>Intro</b>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="img/summer.png">
            </span>
            <b>Summer</b>   
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="img/design.png">
            </span>
            <b>Web Design</b>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="img/schedule.png">
            </span>
            <b>Schedule</b>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="img/site.png">
            </span>
            <b>School Site</b>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="img/goals.png">
            </span>
            <b>Goals</b>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**And this is my CSS:**

```
body {
font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
}

.content-container {
width: 100%;
height: 80vh;
text-align: center;
color: black;
font-size: 42px;
}

.slider {
width: 1200px;
height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
top:250px;
}

.intro-content h3 {
margin-top: -30px;
}

.main-nav {
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
width: 100%;
background-color: #101518;
}

.main-nav ul {
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
color:white;
text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px 35px;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
-o-transition:.3s ;
-ms-transition:.3s;
-moz-transition:.3s;
-webkit-transition:.3s;
transition:.3s;
}

.main-nav ul li:not(.active) {
opacity: 0.5;
}

.main-nav ul li:hover {
opacity: 1;
}

.main-nav span {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
display: block;
margin:0 auto 5px;
}

html {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url("../img/landscape.jpg") no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

What exactly do I need to do from here? I was thinking maybe doing an onclick function that switches the active class so that the non-active class is display:none, but I want it to have a sliding effect. I would really appreciate any help. If you need me to clarify anything please let me know.

Comment: you can use [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) or [Stellar](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variety of plugins as mentioned by Fabio above, or you might use this code as your starting point - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k6ar1ps2/).

Your link to coolcarousels showed it going horizontally, so that's how the fiddle works.

JS

```
$("#selector a").on("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").stop().animate({
                       scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left,
                       scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
                                    },
                                     1200);
                                            });
```

Attribution is noted in the JS section of the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I used a very simple script from this website;

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

Simply download and include Cycle2 plugin on your page (Make sure you also have the latest version of Jquery) and then declare your slideshow markup. There are loads of demo's on the site which are extremely easy to follow.

Goodluck with your project!